# Clang bug? Using pointer as template argument

Tags: c++, templates, clang, clang++

I want to use a pointer as a template argument. Generally, this works fine.
But further, I want those pointers to be declared via another template class.

I have it working fine on GCC, but it is failing on Clang.

Here is a small program to demonstrate ([live link](https://godbolt.org/z/veYP5a)):

```
template <size_t ID = 0>
struct PointerHolderT {
    static thread_local char *smt_pStorage;
};
template <size_t ID>
thread_local char *PointerHolderT<ID>::smt_pStorage = nullptr;

template<char **ppData>
struct MyClass {
    static void foo() {
        cout << "this is my ptr: " << ppData << endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    MyClass<&PointerHolderT<123>::smt_pStorage>::foo(); 
    return 0;
}
```

The error is:

```
error: non-type template argument of type 'char **' is not a constant expression
```

As you can see from the more thorough example at the live link, clang handles it fine when it's a plain global pointer, and when it's a pointer inside a plain struct. It's only when using a pointer inside a *templated* struct that it has trouble.

- Is this a clang bug?

  - Or is what I am doing illegal, but GCC is allowing it?
- **Does anyone know a workaround**, so I can get this working on clang?

Comment: I just tried it with MSVC and it also doesn't compile. ```'MyClass': template parameter 'ppData': 'smt_pStorage': a variable with non-static storage duration cannot be used as a non-type argument``` I think this is possibly a GCC bug actually.

Comment: If I remove `thread_local`, it compiles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the issue is with `thread_local`. If I add `thread_local` to `pData` as well, it fails to compile.

Comment: I'd suppose the reason is as follows: for a normal global variable, there is one object (for a template, so one per type, but whatever) for the entire program, so it makes sense to be able to take its address at compile-time. But a thread-local represents many objects created and destroyed at runtime for each thread, and it doesn't have a fixed address (each thread gets its own variable at its own address). There's just no way to make sense of what the address of the variable even *is* in this question. Perhaps the argument to `MyClass` should be a reference-returning functor?

Comment: @HTNW: so are you supposing that GCC's behavior is non-sensical?

Comment: @jwd It could be some sort of GCC extension; you’d have to check the manual. But you clearly can’t rely on it if you don’t want to lock yourself to gcc.